# Display progress percentage in Node.js based on computation progress in called C# program

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

How to show progress percentage on Node.js server based on percentage completion of processing in a C# program called thru Edge.js

All examples that I have seen on the EDGE.js github page show how to call .NET code from Node and once processing finishes at the .NET side then callback is triggered.  What I want is something like a event emitter and listener. So Node should get a percent complete message from C# at periodic intervals until all processing is done.  I am very new to node and C# so not able to synthesize how to go about it.

Comment: Look at [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) it can help.

Comment: My server app is on Node.js not ASP.NET. I am calling a backend C# .NET program to do some processing.

Comment: SignalR can be used in this scenario, I think. C# program can host it. And send realtime notifications to front.